# Why does video.js interfere with html5 video 'muted'

Tags: html, video, video.js

I am using the following video tag on a page so that when the user changes volume it is remembered for subsequent video viewings -

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" id="video1" data-setup="{}" onvolumechange="setVolume(this.volume,this.muted)">
```

setVolume calls a function that does the storing and retrieving of the volume levels.

If I use

```
data-setup="{}" onvolumechange="setVolume(this.volume)"
```

the volume levels are remembered except for if the mute button is pressed. I can omit *data-setup="{}"* and it will work the same

The problem I am having is when I use the following

```
data-setup="{}" onvolumechange="setVolume(this.volume,this.muted)"
```

volume is remembered but muting is not remembered, in fact after a page refresh the volume is set to 100%. But if I omit *data-setup="{}"* then muting is remembered and works fine.

It seems obvious that the *data-setup="{}"* is what is causing this problem. So why is it doing this, what in video.js is conflicting and how do I work around it?

Comment: Yet another problem I am having with video.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957051/how-to-make-localstorage-work-in-opera/16959537?noredirect=1#16959537

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My script needed to be hooked into the video.js ready function first, like so

```
videojs("video1").ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  getVolume(myPlayer);

});
```

then in a setVolume function you need to use *myPlayer.muted(true);* instead of the normal html5 video API way *myPlayer.muted = true;*

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.