# How to make localStorage work in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, video, local-storage

I have written some javascript code that utilizes [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/). It works in all browsers (ie. FF IE, Safari, Chrome) except for Opera, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Opera you  are using? Opera supports local storage from version 10.5.
You can check that browser is supporting local storage or not by this function.

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
      } catch (e) {
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: You are right, it does work. It came down to the question I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956437/why-does-video-js-interfere-with-html5-video-muted The values were always being stored by Opera, I just can't set the volume of the video player with the script I am using unless I remove the video.js data-setup="{}" bit. All other browsers work fine except Opera which seems to conflict. Strange stuff.